# Generate link to corresponding page in subdir

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I am working on a PHP app that will be installed by end users on their own web servers.

I need to create a link that will direct a visitor to a corresponding page in a subdirectory.

Or example, if the visitor lands on `example.com/open.php`, the link should direct them to `example.com/dir1/open.php`.

I could probably figure this out if `example.com` was static, but as the URL will be different for every end user I can't figure out how to approach this.

Comment: Everything you need is in [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) global. Load a file in browser that just does `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER);` to easily see all it contains that is available for you to use

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm probably more of a n00b than you assume. `[PHP_SELF] => /dir1/view.php` looks potentially useful. Now I need to figure out how to convert that to `/dir1/dir2/view.php`.

Comment: That's just basic string manipulation. There is probably a more conventional routing approach for whatever it is you need to accomplish though. Not really clear what higher level use case is

Comment: use htaccess to rewrite the path you dont have to specify the host

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @johnSmith. But that would redirect everyone automatically. I need this to be a user's choice.

Answer (score 1):

It took 2 hours, but I finally worked out a solution:

`location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + '/dir1/' + window.location.pathname.split(";")[0].split("/").pop();`

Before:
https://example.com/open.php

After:
https://example.com/dir1/open.php